# Why is the annihilator of $c_0 = {0}$?

Tags: functional-analysis

Let $V$be a normed vector space, if $M\subset V$ the set

$$
M^{\perp} = \{x^* \in V^* : x^*(x) = 0 \ \forall x \in M \}
$$
is called the annihilator of $M$.

Now let $M = V = c_0$ the space of sequences, for which the limit is $0$

Why is $c_o^{\perp} = \{0\}$?

Comment: What is the norm on $c_0$?

Comment: $\|\cdot\|_{\infty}$ @UmbertoP.

Comment: Can you prove that the subspace consisting of finite sequences (sequences that are eventually all zeros) is dense in $M$?

Comment: No, the closure of $M$ is not equal to $c_0$. @UmbertoP.

Comment: So the question is: what are the linear functionals that vanish on the whole space?  More generally, you can do the case $M=V$ without mention of $c_0$.

Comment: I mean, in some sense. I seems impossible to come up with a functional such that $x^*(x) = 0$ $\forall x in V$. Because there are infinitly many points $x \in V$, so the only guarantee is $0(x) = 0$. but, it's not much of a proof. @GEdgar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $V$ be a topological vector space and $\varphi\in V^*$, if $\varphi\in V^\perp$, then $\varphi(v)=0$ for all $v\in V$, i.e. $\varphi=0$, hence $V^\perp=\{0\}$.